# Accessing /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d from helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, mariadb, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to initialize a fresh instance of MariaDB (putting my .sql file inside /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d) using the official helm chart at https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mariadb#initialize-a-fresh-instance.

But I find the instructions quite unclear:

> In order to execute the scripts, they must be located inside the chart folder `files/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` so they can be consumed as a ConfigMap.

Since the only thing I do to set up the Mariadb cluster is using their `helm install --name my-release stable/mariadb -f values-production.yaml` I am quite confuse.

Where is this folder ?

---

#### Edit

I downloaded https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mariadb and placing (the whole folder) and placed my SQL file inside `files/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`.

I then used `helm package ./mariadb` followed by `helm install ./mariadb -f ./mariadb/values-production.yaml`. But the master pod has "CrashLoopBackOff" as status.

Here are the master logs

```
==> ** Starting MariaDB setup **
==> Validating settings in MYSQL_*/MARIADB_* env vars..
==> Initializing mariadb database...
==> Persisted data detected. Restoring...
==> Loading user's custom files from /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d ...
==> Stopping mariadb...
```

I also tried this way, but the db keep crashing

```
kubectl create configmap db-scheme --from-file=db.sql
helm install --name db-test stable/mariadb -f .values-production.yml --set rootUser.password=ROOT_PASSWORD --set replication.password=REPLICATION_PASSWORD --set initdbScriptsConfigMap=db-scheme
```

Here are the logs :

[image]

---

#### Edit2

I created a folder named `files/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

My current directory:

```
.
├── values-production.yml
│
├── files
│   └── docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
│       └── db.sql
```

And run this command from the current directory:

```
helm install --name test stable/mariadb -f .\values-production.yml --set rootUser.password=ROOT_PASSWORD --set replication.password=REPLICATION_PASSWORD
```

MariaDB boots up but without my SQL tables.

Comment: Hi @shellwhale (great name btw), please refrain from pasting screenshots of code/logs. You may find some reasoning for this here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11102471

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My issue is more complex than it seems :
https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb/issues/182

Something apart, creating a configmap does indeed work :

```
kubectl create configmap db-scheme --from-file=db.sql

helm install --name db-test stable/mariadb -f .values-production.yml --set rootUser.password=ROOT_PASSWORD --set replication.password=REPLICATION_PASSWORD --set initdbScriptsConfigMap=db-scheme
```

Comment: This seems like the path of least resistance. The chart keeps linking to the galera docker image from bitnami, where you either need to mount a volume or actually copy your sql file into /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d folder and then use that custom image, but then you might have to maintain your own chart.

Answer (score 0):

That chart is a bit awkward, but let me explain, They will create [this configmap](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/mariadb/templates/initialization-configmap.yaml) which reads info of that folder (relatively of the `values.yaml` path).

For your luck, you two more alternatives:

- Pass the scripts you want inlined on your values.yaml ([Line 122](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/1a25e6f5a1ef5367458f51ec1e22d4a788f2d9f0/stable/mariadb/values.yaml#L122))
- Creates aside a configmap with your scripts and refer the name on your values.yaml ([Line 129](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/1a25e6f5a1ef5367458f51ec1e22d4a788f2d9f0/stable/mariadb/values.yaml#L129))

Comment: I don't get it. Am I supposed to clone the chart, place my .sql file inside the files/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d folder, run helm package and helm install ? Because that give me a CrashLoopBackOff

Comment: if you want to go with the default options, on your command `helm install --name my-release stable/mariadb -f values-production.yaml`, make sure you have a folder with the name `files` on your current dir with the scripts.

Comment: Please see my edit2. I created a folder with the name `files` Mariadb boots up but without my sql tables.